# C# Gtk NodeView, how to refresh

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am tinkering with treenode widget in Mono. When I have changed the node it dosnt refresh immediately. I only refreshes when I change the selection of the nodeview. How can I force it to refresh immediately after the change?

Comment: Are you changing it from main thread?

Answer (score 1):

I supose as I wrote in comment that you're not updating the node from the main thread.
There are two easy solutions for this, first is to wakeup main thread after change via `ThreadNotify` class or use `Application.Invoke` to run the updating method in main thread context.

More info about using this techniques can be found [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Responsive_Applications).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Gtk.NodeView? Try `QueueDraw()`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to fire the [`Changed` event](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=E%3aGtk.ITreeNode.Changed) (or invoke the [`OnChanged` method](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aGtk.TreeNode.OnChanged%28%29), in case your nodes inherit from [`TreeNode`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TreeNode)) to notify the node view that a particular node has changed.